# Why does CTRL+ALT+DEL only work from one side of the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I've noticed that on certain computers or keyboards, you can hit the CTRL and ALT keys on either side of the space bar to reboot the computer. However, on some computers, only the left side keys work. Is this something that dates back to the original PC or some quirk that certain systems did not follow?

Comment: The two control keys should be identical, but some systems distinguish between `Alt` on the left and `AltGr` on the right, and where this distinction is made only the left `Alt` key can be part of the sequence. Also, there may be two `Del` keys, one grouped with the function keys, the other in the numeric pad, and either can be used if `NumLock` is disabled.